# Scipy interp2d function produces z = f(x,y), I would like to solve for x

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using the 2d interpolation function in scipy to smooth a 2d image.  As I understand it, interpolate will return z = f(x,y).  What I want to do is find x with known values of y and z.  I tried something like this;

f = interp2d(x,y,z)

index = (np.abs(f(:,y) - z)).argmin()

However the interp2d object does not work that way.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hi @Stephen, welcome to StackOverflow. To note: 1. You can delete comments, and 2. you're [most welcome to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (as an answer, not as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  yvalue, zvalue, xmin, and xmax are known values.  By creating a linspace out of the possible values x can take on, a list can be created with all of the corresponding function values.  Then using argmin() we can find the closest value in the list to the known z value.

f = interp2d(x,y,z)

xnew = numpy.linspace(xmin, xmax)

fnew = f(xnew, yvalue)

xindex = (numpy.abs(fnew - zvalue)).argmin()

xvalue = xnew(xindex)